# bcrypt causing unit testing to go crazy

Tags: unit-testing, bcrypt

I am using Webpack. Karma and Mocha to run a unit test:

```
const assert = require('assert');
//const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

describe('encryptPass', function() {
    it('returned hash should return ', function() {
        assert.equal(1, 1);
    });
});
```

When I comment out the bcrypt include line, the test runs fine. However, when I leave this line in, it prints a whole load of information and errors to the console:

```
> auth_app@1.0.0 test /tidee/auth_app
> NODE_ENV=test karma start

Hash: 745e3239cb5645ae9c7c
Version: webpack 1.14.0
Time: 15923ms
                                 Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
 79515ad0788973c533405f7012dfeccd.woff  22.7 kB          [emitted]
  f4769f9bdb7466be65088239c12046d1.eot  20.1 kB          [emitted]
9b281482a6fbc52739698e0c130ea52a.woff2  11.3 kB          [emitted]
 1fff7dfa22a6c8ba9382ad03726139d3.woff  27.1 kB          [emitted]
 f2bce001e16fa48466239a51378474d1.woff    28 kB          [emitted]
 36eeac2edc10f0533f49c8e008896e40.woff  38.4 kB          [emitted]
 6a00de061f4fcc2ae24f25da53a02f4d.woff  13.2 kB          [emitted]
 fa2772327f55d8198301fdb8bcfc8158.woff  23.4 kB          [emitted]
448c34a56d699c29117adc64c43affeb.woff2    18 kB          [emitted]
  89889688147bd7575d6327160d64e760.svg   109 kB          [emitted]
                                  main  5.62 MB       0  [emitted]  main
        tests/unit/encryptPass_test.js  14.3 MB       1  [emitted]  tests/unit/encryptPass_test.js
chunk    {0} main (main) 5.43 MB
    [0] multi main 28 bytes {0}
    [1] ./~/react/react.js 56 bytes {0} [built]
    [2] ./~/process/browser.js 5.3 kB {0} {1} [built]
    [3] ./~/moment/moment.js 123 kB {0} [built]
    [4] ./~/babel-runtime/helpers/classCallCheck.js 208 bytes {0} [built]
    [5] ./~/babel-runtime/helpers/inherits.js 1.11 kB {0} [built]
    [6] ./~/babel-runtime/helpers/possibleConstructorReturn.js 542 bytes {0} [built]
    [7] ./~/babel-runtime/helpers/extends.js 544 bytes {0} [built]
    [8] ./~/babel-runtime/helpers/objectWithoutProperties.js 280 bytes {0} [built]
    [9] ./~/classnames/index.js 1.1 kB {0} [built]
   [10] ./~/react-bootstrap/lib/utils/bootstrapUtils.js 5.7 kB {0} [built]
   [11] ./~/fbjs/lib/invariant.js 1.49 kB {0} [built]
   [12] ./~/fbjs/lib/warning.js 2.1 kB {0} [built]
   [13] ./~/react-dom/lib/reactProdInvariant.js 1.24 kB {0} [built]
   [14] ./~/react-prop-types/lib/elementType.js 1.44 kB {0} [built]
   [15] ./~/object-assign/index.js 1.99 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [16] ./~/buffer/index.js 48.6 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [17] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMComponentTree.js 6.16 kB {0} [built]
   [18] ./~/invariant/browser.js 1.52 kB {0} [built]
   [19] ./~/mongoose/lib/utils.js 18 kB {0} [built]
   [20] ./~/warning/browser.js 1.81 kB {0} [built]
   [21] ./~/fbjs/lib/ExecutionEnvironment.js 1.06 kB {0} [built]
   [22] ./~/mongoose/lib/error.js 1.34 kB {0} [built]
   [23] ./~/react-bootstrap/lib/utils/createChainedFunction.js 1.04 kB {0} [built]
   [24] ./~/react-bootstrap/lib/utils/StyleConfig.js 573 bytes {0} [built]
   [25] ./~/react-dom/index.js 59 bytes {0} [built]
   [26] ./~/mongoose/lib/schematype.js 26.5 kB {0} [built]
   [27] ./~/react-bootstrap/lib/utils/ValidComponentChildren.js 4.36 kB {0} [built]
   [28] ./~/react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook.js 10.4 kB {0} [built]
   [29] ./~/axios/lib/utils.js 7.46 kB {0} [built]
   [30] ./~/jquery/dist/jquery.js 267 kB {0} [built]
   [31] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactInstrumentation.js 601 bytes {0} [built]
   [32] ./~/fbjs/lib/emptyFunction.js 1.08 kB {0} [built]
   [33] ./~/mongoose/lib/document.js 68.8 kB {0} [built]
   [34] ./~/core-js/library/modules/_core.js 117 bytes {0} [built]
   [35] ./~/core-js/library/modules/_wks.js 368 bytes {0} [built]
   [36] ./~/react-bootstrap/lib/SafeAnchor.js 3.8 kB {0} [built]
   [37] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactUpdates.js 9.53 kB {0} [built]
   [38] ./~/react-intl/lib/index.js 62.1 kB {0} [built]
   [39] ./~/react/lib/ReactCurrentOwner.js 623 bytes {0} [built]
   [40] ./~/react-dom/lib/SyntheticEvent.js 9.18 kB {0} [built]
   [41] ./client/src/helpers/doFetch.js 4.55 kB {0} [built]
...
WARNING in ./~/bcrypt/bcrypt.js
Critical dependencies:
6:15-36 the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./~/bcrypt/bcrypt.js 6:15-36

WARNING in ./~/node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding.js
Critical dependencies:
19:22-48 the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./~/node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding.js 19:22-48

WARNING in ./~/bcrypt/CHANGELOG.md
Module parse failed: /tidee/auth_app/node_modules/bcrypt/CHANGELOG.md Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/tidee/auth_app/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp$7.getTokenFromCode (/tidee/auth_app/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2756:10)
    at Parser.pp$7.readToken (/tidee/auth_app/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2477:17)
    at Parser.pp$7.nextToken (/tidee/auth_app/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2468:15)
    at Parser.parse (/tidee/auth_app/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:515:10)
    at Object.parse (/tidee/auth_app/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (/tidee/auth_app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
    at NormalModule.<anonymous> (/tidee/auth_app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at NormalModule.onModuleBuild (/tidee/auth_app/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
    at nextLoader (/tidee/auth_app/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
    at /tidee/auth_app/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
    at Storage.finished (/tidee/auth_app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
    at /tidee/auth_app/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:415:3)
 @ ./~/bcrypt ^\.\/.*$
```

and it goes on an on!!

Comment: What's in `~/bcrypt`? It looks like you may have installed it incorrectly.

Comment: bcrypt is an npm package. It seems to be working ok in other areas of the application that are using it. Wondering if it is a problem with the way I have set up the testing environment (?)